# Massaction without selecting items magento

Tags: php, magento

What I need is something simple, you have some way to create a MassAction, however without having to select the items (if ever will be for all items).

Is there any option that I can put in the creation of MassAction for this to occur?

Whenever you do not select an item by default it returns a message saying it must be selected at least one item.

**@EDIT**

This is where it validates it would have some way to go through this validation without rewriting the CORE?

js\mage\adminhtml\grid.js

```
apply: function() {

    if(varienStringArray.count(this.checkedString) == 0) {
            alert(this.errorText);
            return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks as though the mass action works on post:
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model

```
public function massactionPrepareKey()
{
    $request = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest();
    if ($key = $request->getPost('massaction_prepare_key')) {
        $value = is_array($request->getPost($key)) ? $request->getPost($key) : explode(',', $request->getPost($key));
        $request->setPost($key, $value ? $value : null);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Probably the easiest way is to modify the mass action JS to select all items before it posts.

The JS for this is in js/mage/adminhtml/grid.js.  I have to run, so I can't figure out exactly how to do it right now, but you can start by looking here:

```
selectAll: function() {
        this.setCheckedValues((this.useSelectAll ? this.getGridIds() : this.getCheckboxesValuesAsString()));
        this.checkCheckboxes();
        this.updateCount();
        this.clearLastChecked();
        return false;
    },
```

This looks to be what Magento is using to select all items.